# Regex To Match Same Characters After Each Other PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a Regex to match something where the character is the same 5 10 times in a row or more. Yet this does not seem to be working. It needs to work for UTF-8 aswell. The thing I am using is:

```
preg_match("~(.)\1{9,}~u", "string");
```

Yet it never seems to match the string I want. A couple of examples are:

```
aaaaa (5) [Should NOT be matched]
aaaaaaaaaaaa (12) [Should BE matched]
```

**EDIT**

Ok it is now working, somewhat anyhow. If the user inputs

```
aaaaa(5) aaaaaaaaaaaa(12)
```

It will not say it matches the regex, I think it is because of the space diving the group of letters.

Comment: Use single quotes. `\1` means something else in double-quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your regex inside single quotes. And also it's better to use anchors, so that it would do an exact line match. Or otherwise , it would match `oooooooooo` in `foooooooooobar` string.

```
preg_match('~^(.)\1{9,}$~mu', "string");
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/wF9yU4/2)

Comment: Hello, thank you! :) My issue was I was using double quotes. Also thank you for the tip on using MU :)

Comment: yep, your problem is double quotes but also consider using anchors. [Accept if this helps.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Oh, couple you please help me a little bit? I am testing my regex now, and it only matches the first input. For instance if I input "aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa" it does not match the second set that goes over 10.

Comment: because it contain a space. Please explain your problem clrealy by adding some details  to your question.

Comment: Hello, I have still been doing a bit more work on it. And I have found 2 - 3 three more things if you would like to help! :) First I would like to to match something even if it is in another string, such as oooooooooooo in fooooooooooooobar. Then  I would like it to not be case sensitive (if that is easy though :) ). Then lastly it does not match if there items longer then 10 and they are spaced, but different characters, a example is here https://www.regex101.com/r/wF9yU4/4.

Comment: Hello, much better, but it counts spaces. Like aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa would match the space in the middle too. Also is there a case sensitive thing?

Comment: Oh, I got the case insensitive part! :) The only problem now is the matching of spaces

Comment: Everything is now PERFECT! :) Thank you for all of your help

Comment: Oh yes sorry! :) I did not know I could vote up yet :)